# OpenDaylight Nitrogen: where to specify repository for features?

Tags: maven, apache-karaf, opendaylight

Where do I specify repository paths in OpenDaylight Nitrogen (on Karaf 4.0)? I am building a Java application on this platform. I noticed that `features.xml` is generated from the POM. I need to load some features from my local Maven `.m2/repository` that are generated from another project. I see a `features/features-X` directory with a `pom.xml` where I can add the feature dependency, but where do I specify the repository in which to look for the feature?

This is probably more of a Maven question than an OpenDaylight question....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is somewhat OpenDaylight-specific (although obviously the behaviour can be replicated using Maven in other contexts). As you’ve discovered, Karaf feature descriptors are now generated automatically, based on the POM dependencies. For this to work, the following requirements must be met:

- the feature-generating module must have `org.opendaylight.odlparent:single-feature-parent` as its parent (transitively if necessary);
- the POM must specify `feature` as its `packaging` type;
- feature dependencies should be declared as build dependencies in the POM, using the default scope, with `type` set to `xml` and `classifier` set to `features` (plural).

If necessary, feature snippets can be given as `src/main/feature/feature.xml` (singular) in the corresponding module; these will be merged with the generated `feature.xml` (singular again). The result is installed as a `features.xml` (plural) file in the target repository.

It’s worth noting that feature descriptors generated in this fashion use each feature they depend upon as their own repositories; if you need a multi-feature repository instead, you should use a manually-generated feature descriptor.

This is briefly documented in [the ODL Parent developer guide](http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-nitrogen/developer-guide/odl-parent-developer-guide.html#single-feature-parent).

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in as a dependency in  features/features-X/pom.xml the plugin looks at the maven path and automatically generates the repository. ( Answering my own question so it could be of use to others. )